# JavaScript Unit Tests with Team Foundation Server Build

Tags: javascript, tfs, jasmine, tfsbuild

We are using Team Foundation Server 2010 and we have some JavaScript unit tests running on our local machines using [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/).

We are using the workflow based builds.

Has anyone had any success running Jasmine tests during their builds? Can you break the build if the Jasmine tests fail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I've seen this done is using the Chutzpah Test Runner available on CodePlex: http://chutzpah.codeplex.com/

This allows you to run Jasmine/QUnit tests from a command-line which can then be easily integrated with a TFSBuild using the InvokeProcess Activity.

Comment: Thanks Dylan, Chutzpah looks like the way to go!

Comment: These [setup instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/07/09/javascript-unit-tests-on-team-foundation-service-with-chutzpah.aspx) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you should checkout http://www.codit.eu/blog/2015/03/18/continuous-integration-with-javascript-nunit-on-tfsbuild-(part-23)/

The blogpost describes a complete scenario how to execute your JavaScript Unit tests on the Team Foundation Build server. Basically it uses Grunt (taskrunner) and Powershell. It also has an example of code coverage reports that you can use.